# phpunit reflectionexception error on Mocks

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I've been following a tutorial on phpUnit but i can't seem to make it work.

here's the link:

https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-4-mock-objects-stub-methods-dependency-injection/

```
There was 1 error:

1) phpUnitTutorial\Test\PaymentTest::testProcessPaymentReturnsTrueOnSuccess
ReflectionException: Class Mock_AuthorizeNetAIM_2d93f549 does not have a constructor, so     you cannot pass any constructor arguments
```

**phpUnitTutorial/Payment.php**

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial;

class Payment
{
    const API_ID = 123456;
    const TRANS_KEY = 'TRANSACTION KEY';

    //Use Dependency Injection
    public function processPayment(\AuthorizeNetAIM $transaction, array $paymentDetails)
    {
        $transaction->amount = $paymentDetails['amount'];
        $transaction->card_num = $paymentDetails['card_num'];
        $transaction->exp_date = $paymentDetails['exp_date'];

        $response = $transaction->authorizeAndCapture();

        if ($response->approved) {
            return $this->savePayment($response->transaction_id);
        }

        throw new \Exception($response->error_message);
    }

    public function savePayment($transactionId)
    {
        // Logic for saving transaction ID to database or anywhere else would go in here
        return true;
    }
}
```

**phpUnitTutorial/Test/PaymentTest.php**

```
<?php

namespace phpUnitTutorial\Test;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../Payment.php';
use phpUnitTutorial\Payment;

class PaymentTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testProcessPaymentReturnsTrueOnSuccess()
    {
        $paymentDetails = array(
            'amount' => 123.99,
            'card_num' => '4111-111-111-111',
            'exp_date' => '03/2013'
        );

        $payment = new Payment();

        // Note stdClass is used to conveniently create a generic
        // class
        $response = new \stdClass();
        $response->approved = true;
        $response->transaction_id = 123;

        $authorizeNet = $this->getMockBuilder('\AuthorizeNetAIM')
             ->setConstructorArgs(
                 array(
                     $payment::API_ID,
                     $payment::TRANS_KEY
                 )
             )->getMock();

        // $authorizeNet =  $this
        //     ->getMock(
        //         '\AuthorizeNetAIM',
        //         array(),
        //         array($payment::API_ID, $payment::TRANS_KEY)
        //     );

        $authorizeNet->expects($this->once())
            ->method('authorizeAndCapture')
            ->will($this->returnValue($response));

        $result = $payment->processPayment($authorizeNet, $paymentDetails);

        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has `\AuthorizeNetAIM` own constructor?

Comment: No, it's a library. Here it is https://github.com/ajbdev/authorizenet-php-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\AuthorizeNetAIM` has no constructor - as the error message states. So you can't pass any arguments to it. Create the mock in this way:

```
$authorizeNet = $this->getMockBuilder('\AuthorizeNetAIM')->getMock();
```

or shorter:

```
$authorizeNet = $this->getMock('\AuthorizeNetAIM');
```

Comment: yeah, that's what i've been thinking but there seems to be a constructor since on the tutorial on my link, the author instantitiated it with 2 parameters.

Here's the snippet from the tutorial.  $transaction = new \AuthorizeNetAIM(self::API_ID, self::TRANS_KEY);

Comment: Could you point where in the documentation this snippet is? I can't find it - every example has building this object without any arguments.

Comment: i've followed the tutorial on this https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-4-mock-objects-stub-methods-dependency-injection/.
You can immediately see it on the start of the tutorial.

Comment: sorry, but what documenation are you referrring to? is it on AuthorizeNetAim docs? if it is i haven't seen the docs yet.
I've simply followed the tutorial as it is. I think i have to look up the the library's API itself.

Comment: I've reffered to the documentation from github. Maybe tutorial you've pointed is basing on an older version of this library or just has a mistake. Take a look on unit tests from this project. And pay attention that class AuthorizeNetRequest takes API_ID and TRANSACTION_KEY as its arguments.

Comment: thanks a lot. yeah, maybe it was an author mistake.
I'm just about to look up the docs from github. :)